# How to avoid internet verification on wifi network in android 5.0 and higher

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an application that needs to connect to a wifi network, but this wifi network has a captive portal in which you have to make a click in a button to get internet access in that network.

My problem is that in android 5.0 and higher the OS do not connect the wifi network because it first checks if the wifi network has internet access if a mobile network with internet access is present. I want to connect to the wifi network even without internet access because i want to handle the captive portal in my app.

Is there a way to do this? because android detects it is connected to the wifi network but because is has no internet access it still uses the mobile network adapter.

I know that one option is to redirect all the traffic from my app to the wifi adapter but I would rather to not do that. But to just tell android to connect to the wifi network even without internet.

Thanks!

Comment: `in android 5.0 and higher the OS do not connect the wifi network because it first checks if the wifi network has internet access`. Nonsense. What makes you think so?

Comment: Ok. You ment that it will not connect if a mobile connection is available. Well switch off mobile connection then.

Comment: `I know that one option is to redirect all the traffic from my app to the wifi adapter `. I do not know that and i have no idea how that should be done.

Comment: you can redirect the traffic by using the method bindProcessToNetwork(network) in ConnectivityManager.  it will make that the all requests from the app use that network you passed as parameter.

Comment: How could I switch off mobile connection?

Comment: Programmatically not i think. The user should do that.

Comment: I see, ,that is not an option. I will keep looking at least for a workaround